Problem with AxesLabel position in three-dimensional plot
I have the following code:
ResourceFunction["MaTeXInstall"][]; << MaTeX`

plot = Show[ContourPlot3D[{x + y - 2 z == 0}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
Mesh -> False, ViewPoint -> {-2.1, -2.5, 0.7}, 
AxesLabel -> {MaTeX["\\delta", Magnification -> 1.25], 
  Rotate[MaTeX["P\\,(10^{21}\\,\\mathrm{g}/\\mathrm{cm}^{3})", 
    Magnification -> 1.25], 330 Degree], 
  MaTeX["\\mu", Magnification -> 1.25]},
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}}], Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.035], Point[{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}]}]];

legend = SwatchLegend[{Orange, Blue, Green}, {MaTeX["\\alpha"], 
MaTeX["\\beta"], MaTeX["\\gamma"]}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}];

FINALPLOT = Legended[Style[Row[{plot, plot, plot}], ImageSizeMultipliers -> {0.75, 0.75}],Placed[legend, {0.5, 1}]]

The result is this:

As you can see, the label $P(10^{21}\mathrm{g}/\mathrm{cm}^3)$ is not well located, and I would like to move it closer to its corresponding axis. I have tried using Slicer, Overlay, Inset and Epilog, with no success, and making the code way too messy. I think there must be some straightforward command to move the axes labels, but I do not manage to find it.
